# Apply Ensemble for timeseries forecasting

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, holtwinters, arima

I'm using multiple timeseries models like ARIMA, holtwinters, prophet. Now I want to do ensemble of all this and produce the results . I need suggestions what is the best way to apply ensemble on timeseries. Please help. I'm new to this.

Answer (score 2):

There is a recent package called tsensembler (full disclose, I am the author).

[link for documentation with useful examples](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tsensembler/versions/0.0.2)

[link for github](https://github.com/vcerqueira/tsensembler)

It essentially trains a set of regression models for predicting the next value(s) of the time series, and combines them automatically using a metalearning approach. The scientific basis was presented in the conference ECML-PKDD2017, and it won the best student machine learning paper award.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest exploring the opera package.

```
install.packages("opera")
```

Here is the vignette:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/opera/vignettes/opera-vignette.html

Answer (score -1):

The following link provides sample code and walks through using two ensemble packages in R.  The packages are 'opera' and 'forecastHybrid'.

[Opera & forecastHybrid](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/forecast-combinations/)